# ksh behaves differently for telnet command

Tags: bash, ksh, telnet

I am trying to do telnet a Linux host inside ksh script, but the output seems to different when the same script is executed as bash script. Anyone has any Ideas ?

When the script when executed as bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e '\x1dclose\x0d' | telnet myhost myport > /dev/null 2>&1
echo $?
```

output of $? is 0

Same script when executed as ksh results value of $? is 1

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo -e '\x1dclose\x0d' | telnet myhost myport > /dev/null 2>&1
echo $?
```

Any one have any ideas ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Looks like the 2nd one gets an error. remove `> /dev/null 2>&1` and compare the output

Comment: dont use `echo`. use `printf`.

Comment: @Jens IF you look at the scripts both are same except one is executed in bash. The server & port that i am trying to telnet is up and running so I am expecting ksh script to give same output as bash script one

Comment: @pynexj I tried with printf in both ksh and bash shell and still the outputs are different in both shell                         output from ksh shell : printf "\x1dclose\x0d" | telnet myhost myport results in 1 whereas same command in bash results in 0

Comment: @user23348485 If you not see what is happening, you will not see why you have a difference. My guess is that you have a different encoding via telnet

Comment: maybe the Hex char c of close confuses printf. try sth like `printf '\x1d%s\x0d' close`.

Comment: u also need `\n`

Answer (score 2):

The return value, of `telnet` is 1 if the remote host closes the connection (or any remote or network error occurs) and 0 if the local client side closes the connection successfully. My guess is, that `bash` terminates the client a bit quicker than `ksh`, so in the `ksh` version, the remote host may be a bit quicker closing the session. That being said, if you put some heavy load on your client system, the version in `bash` may also return a 1. The return value of `telnet` is not as helpful as you might think.

Also, `telnet` is an interactive program that is not really suited for the use in scripts. Use `nc` if the interaction is simple, or `expect` if the interaction becomes more complex.

Answer (score 1):

`printf \x` behaves differently between ksh and bash, try to use octal notation

```
printf '\035close\x0d' | telnet myhost myport > /dev/null 2>&1
```